# Making testSteps interact with each others using SOAPUI

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui, testcase

I'm new at using SOAPUI and I can't find how to properly test the REST URI on my server.

I want to test POST, PUT and DELETE on a given URI.

The **POST** method should create a new entry in my database and the server returns the generated key to access this element.

The **PUT** method is used to update an entry and required a JSON containing the key of the entry to be updated.

The **DELETE** method takes the key of the entry to be deleted.

So, I want to create a testCase for each URI with 3 testSteps

- first step: Posting JSON to that URI, create a new entry and retrieve its key
- second step: Updating the previous entry (I don't know how to generate a JSON containing the key)
- third step: deleting that entry (same problem)

The key is generated by the server, so I have to retrieve it and pass it to the other steps.

So my question is in two parts:

- How can I retrieve the response of the server ?
- How can I generate the JSON to be sent by the two others steps ?

If you need more informations to answer my question, feel free to ask :)

I hope someone could give me some clues in order to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if this answers your question, but this is what I did to grab JSON from the response string

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurper = new JsonSlurper() 

def prevStepResponse = '${Create Customer - All fields#Response}'
def prevRespString = context.expand(prevStepResponse) 
def prev = slurper.parseText(prevRespString)

assert prev.customerId > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the response of the server after , I found out how to do.

```
def response = context.expand( '${Request 1#Response}' )
```

This gives a String representation of the server's response.

Now I have to extract some parts of the response and create a JSON which will be sent to the next step (PUT request). I still have to find out how.

Any help ?